# Fit image 1 size to image 2

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have some images pairs; img1 and img2.
They may have these dimensions for example:

img1.shape is (392,489), img2.shape is (394,492).
img1.shape is (392,489), img2.shape is (394,486).
img1.shape is (392,489), img2.shape is (389,492).
img1.shape is (392,489), img2.shape is (389,486).

How could I end up, for each case, with two images of exactly the same shape easily (maximal overlapping area)?

For the moment, let say the top-left corner is (0,0) and should stay here in all images to make the problem easier.

#### Update:

Here's my workaround for the moment:

```
    (w1,h1) = img1.shape
    (w2,h2) = img2.shape
    widths  = (w1,w2)
    heights = (h1,h2)
    new_shape   = (min(widths),min(heights))
    new_img1 = img1[:new_shape[0],:new_shape[1]]
    new_img2 = img2[:new_shape[0],:new_shape[1]]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why are your images in numpy instead of using PIL? Stackexchange is *not* a coding service where you can drop your requirements and expect someone to code the solution for you.

Comment: You are absolutely right, that's why I updated the main post. I thought the answer would have been some function name I ignore e.g.

Comment: Have you looked at np.pad?

Comment: You have to decide !  Your solution is the fastest, but  you loss some informations at edges. if the loss is without importance, let it like that, else you have to resize, ant that cost time. Is it what you want ?